# New "part of a coding contest" reason for closing question?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, flags, vote-to-close, close-reasons

Seeing [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35251319/why-does-the-algorithm-for-finding-diameter-of-tree-not-work-for-graphs#35251319) question (and others like it), it was remarked on as being part of a code contest.
This seemed to me as a fair reason for flagging the question, but after clicking on "should be closed", no option was really relevant.
More reasons for flagging questions? Maybe an additional level like the "Off topic" section?

Comment: Someone has commented to that effect - http://stackoverflow.com/a/35252638/2802040

Comment: @Paulie_D - I saw that comment, that's how I know it's part of a contest. I'm talking about the fact that there is no real relevant flag for this

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/131331/is-there-a-policy-on-questions-taken-from-prize-bearing-coding-competitions

Comment: Luckily, the competition-abuse questions I've seen have been absolute rubbish anyway and so easily closed for existing reasons.  That said, if I found such a question that was not rubbish, I would downvote it anyway and find some excuse to close vote it.

Comment: According to SE staff, some question beeing part of a coding contest is not a close reason. Luckily, most of them are bad anyways and other reaosns apply.

Answer (score 4):

It's fine to ask questions about homework or contests, as long as the questions are complete and on-topic.

This one is a "fix my code" question without showing any code, so:

> Off-topic: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

The're another question, linked from the comments, about the same subject: [Correctness of algorithm for finding diameter of graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35250604/correctness-of-algorithm-for-finding-diameter-of-graph). This one is too broad, because this is the entire problem statement:

> Can anyone prove its correctness or prove it is false